# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause'

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

```
String hql="from "+ Employee.class.getName()
                  + " where email= ? and password=? ";
List<Employee> emplist=ht.find(hql,email,pwd);
```

This the error I am getting, Can you please help me that.

> ```
> Hibernate: 
>     select
>         employee0_.empid as empid0_,
>         employee0_.empmail as empmail0_,
>         employee0_.empmobile as empmobile0_,
>         employee0_.empname as empname0_,
>         employee0_.emppassword as emppassw5_0_ 
>     from
>         emptab employee0_ 
>     where
>         email=? 
>         and employee0_.emppassword=?
>
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown
> column 'email' in 'where clause'
> ```

Formatted Employee with table name `emptab` code is below:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="emptab") 
public class Employee { 
  @Id
  @Column(name="empid") 
  private int id; 

  @Column(name="empname") 
  private String name; 

  @Column(name="emppassword") 
  private String password; 

  @Column(name="empmail") 
  private String mail; 

  @Column(name="empmobile") 
  private int mobile
  }
```

Comment: Share your Employee.java code

Comment: can you share your mapping

Comment: Entity
Table(name="emptab")
public class Employee {
 @Id
 @Column(name="empid")
 private int id;
 @Column(name="empname")
 private String name;
 @Column(name="emppassword")
 private String password;
 @Column(name="empmail")
 private String mail;
 @Column(name="empmobile")
 private int mobile;

Comment: add employee code in question, not in comments. Edit your question

Comment: I can't find a property **email** in Employee class, that you specified in the query

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be like:

```
String hql="from "+ Employee.class.getName()
                  + " e where e.mail= ? and e.password=? ";
```

Make sure that email and password fields are already present in Employee entity and Employee Table in your DB.

Answer (score 0):

Put Single quote `'` around `?` as email and password are string and then try

```
 String hql="from "+ Employee.class.getName()
            + " AS employee0_ where employee0_.empmail = ? and employee0_.emppassword=? ";
    List<Employee> emplist=ht.find(hql,email,pwd);
```

Comment: tried but new error, org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your hql query,

```
String hql="from "+ Employee.class.getName()
                  + " where email= ? and password=? ";
List<Employee> emplist=ht.find(hql,email,pwd);
```

In the above query, the field "email" is not present in Employee class, change the query to,

```
String hql="from "+ Employee.class.getName()
                  + " where mail= ? and password=? ";
List<Employee> emplist=ht.find(hql,email,pwd);
```

Go through this [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/queryhql.html),  it's highly recommended,

Answer (score 0):

Exception says cannot find `email`, you have no such property in your `Employee` class, its actually `mail`, so change your query like this

```
String hql="from "+ Employee.class.getName() + " where mail= ? and password= ? ";
```